# Addressing related tables in Kohana's ORM where method

Tags: php, sql, orm, kohana

How would you express the following SQL query as a Kohana's ORM request and more specifically the where clause?

```
SELECT items.* 
FROM items 
LEFT JOIN users ON items.user = users.id
WHERE users.name = 'john.doe'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORM::factory('item')->join('users', 'LEFT')->on('item.user', '=', 'users.id')->where('users.name', '=', 'john.doe')->find_all();
```

This will produce the following query:

```
SELECT item.* FROM items LEFT JOIN users ON item.user = users.id WHERE users.name = 'john.doe'
```

Remember to follow Kohana naming convention (i.e. database name should be plural (`users`) but the model should be singular (`Model_User`)).